# How can I fetch the warnings after node-mysql queries

Tags: mysql, node.js, error-handling, node-mysql

How can I fetch the corresponding warning identified after the query execution as in:

```
connection.query( squery, function(err, rows){
   ... 
   // search for OkPacket in 2 dimension array
   var warningCounter = okPacket.warningCount;
   if ( warningCounter > 0 ){
      ???
   }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the query:

```
SHOW WARNINGS
```

Here is more on **[SHOW WARNINGS Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html)**

Comment: So, node-mysql does now not execute it implicitly... I have to relaunch another query from within the query callback or is there another way ?

Comment: Can you tap it onto the end of the SQL?

db.query('INSERT (1,2,3) INTO table; SHOW WARNINGS;', callback);

Comment: @blue - How can SHOW WARNINGS be used safely?

Comment: @AdrianLynch - Here is a question about executing multiple queries with node-mysql: [Approach to multiple MySQL queries with Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6622746/3440995)