# Alternate implementation for nodejs+mysql+Q solution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, node-mysql

I am trying to avoid the pyramid of doom. I have a REST function on my server that returns a "payload" object with three JSON fields for the results. Each of the three fields is calculated with a mysql query call. I figured out the nodejs way of putting the next query in the callback function of the current query, but pyramid of doom beckons!

I found this solution using Q promises which is fantastic, but I cannot figure out from the Q docs how the deferred and .makeNodeResolver work. Also the results object is intimidating and I had to find my results through trial and error... is there an alternative way to solve this problem? Am I making it harder than it has to be?

[Stack Overflow answer with helpful but confusing Q syntax (programath's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622746/approach-to-multiple-mysql-queries-with-node-js)

My code:

```
    var queryHelper = function(request, response, payload)
    {
      var queryQB = queryConstructionHelper(request, '"QB"')
      var queryRB = queryConstructionHelper(request, '"RB"')
      var queryWRTE = queryConstructionHelper(request, '"WRTE"')

      function doQuery1()
      {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        database.query (queryQB, deferred.makeNodeResolver());
        return deferred.promise;
      }
      function doQuery2()
      {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        database.query (queryRB, deferred.makeNodeResolver());
        return deferred.promise;
      }
      function doQuery3()
      {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        database.query (queryWRTE, deferred.makeNodeResolver());
        return deferred.promise;
      }

      Q.all([doQuery1(),doQuery2(),doQuery3()]).then(function(results)
      {
           payLoadAssignHelper('"QB"', payload, results[0][0][0].payloadCount);
           payLoadAssignHelper('"RB"', payload, results[1][0][0].payloadCount);
           payLoadAssignHelper('"WRTE"', payload, results[2][0][0].payloadCount);

          response.send(payload);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Your functions are fine, but you should simplify them using [`Q.nfbind`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnfbindnodefunc-args) instead: `var doQuery1 = Q.nfbind(queryConstructionHelper(request, '"QB"'));`

Comment: Thank you Bergi for your comment but I do not think that will work. There is no execution of database.query... am I right? Looking at my code again, it just seems hacky and janky... let me know if there is another way to express the functionality in queryHelper()

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does work, did you try it? If yes, did you get any error?

Comment: I was going to try it but without database.query being called there really isn't a point. The "queryConstructionHelper()" method just generates a query string. Sorry that my example did not provide that code, I thought it would make my post too verbose.

Comment: Oh right, I messed it up. Should be `var doQuery1 = Q.nfbind(database.query, queryQB)` (or maybe `Q.nbind(database.query, database, queryQB)`) of course

Comment: I tried:

var queryQBCountWithFilter = Q.nfbind(database.query, queryQBCount)

but I get no errors and no result... it is strange, database.query is definitely my nodefunc and it has the one arg, queryQBCount...

Comment: Probably it's missing its `this` values. Try the other version (which is a bit like `database.query.bind(database)`)