# connecting to MySQL async using nodeJs and 'Q'

Tags: mysql, node.js, q

I'm dealing with project using Postgres DB, it uses nodeJs and 'Q' framework. I want to replace postgres DB with mysql database, since I'm a total newbie to nodeJs, I have no idea on how to idea? It will be great if you could share an example of mysql connect and if possible a simple query using nodeJs and 'Q'.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16243390/6099419) answer. It seems to answer your question.

Taken exactly from the the answer:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var Q = require('Q');

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : ''
    });

    connection.connect();

    function doQuery1(){
        var defered = Q.defer();
        connection.query('SELECT 1 AS solution',defered.makeNodeResolver());
        return defered.promise;
    }

    function doQuery2(){
        var defered = Q.defer();
        connection.query('SELECT 2 AS solution',defered.makeNodeResolver());
        return defered.promise;
    }

    Q.all([doQuery1(),doQuery2()]).then(function(results){
        res.send(JSON.stringify(results[0][0][0].solution+results[1][0][0].solution));
    });

    connection.end();
```

However, if you don't need to make multiple calls at once, you can skip the use of  Q.all and just do something like:

```
return doQuery1().then(function(res){
     console.log(res);
     connection.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this is how i ended up doing it in the end:

```
var connection  = mysql.createConnection({host     : 'host',user  :'user', password :  'pass', database :  'db'});

var connect = Q.denodeify(connection.connect.bind(connection));
connect().then(function (values) {
    console.log('...connected to database');
    var query = Q.denodeify(connection.query.bind(connection));
})
```