# Best way to process results of multiple, sequential, dependent mongo queries in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**High level**

I'm new to JS and Node. I'm working on an API endpoint that should return a status value. To compute the status value I need to make two sequential mongo queries where the second set of queries depend on the first query. The second set of queries will give me a status for each value found in the first query, of which I will pick one based on some logic. What is the best way to do it in NodeJS?

**Specifics**

Here are parts of my first attempt.

```
function getItemStatus(key, value, callback) {
        MongoClient.connect(mongo_url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) { return console.dir(err); }
            db.collection('status', function(err, coll) {
                if (err) { return console.dir(err); }
                coll.distinct("_id.metric", function(err, metrics) {
                    if (err) { return console.dir(err); }
                    console.log('metrics : ', metrics);
                    _.foreach(metrics, function(metric) {
                        var query = {"_id": {
                            "$gte" : {key: key, value: value, created: new Date("1800-01-01T00:00:00"), metric : metric},
                            "$lte" : {key: key, value: value, created: new Date("2100-01-01T00:00:00"), metric : metric}}};
                        coll.find(query, {sort: {"_id.created": -1}, limit: 1})
```

I make a connection, query for a set of metric values using a distinct query. For each metric I then want to ask for the latest status. Ideally I'd like to have the entire set of statuses so that I could write a function taking this set and deciding on which status will be returned. My problem is passing the statuses back "up the chain" so that I can process the set of statuses.

In a synchronous situation I would simply write something like this

```
val metrics = getDistinctMetrics(key, value)
val statuses = metrics.map(getStatusForMetric)
val status = filterStatuses(statuses)
```

How can I accomplish this in JavaScript/NodeJS?

**UPDATED** to highlight the fact that the first queries will trigger *several* queries in the second step,  i.e. one for each result found by the first query.

Comment: Excellent answer to thois is in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622746/approach-to-multiple-mysql-queries-with-node-js

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your question you want to execute queries parallel or in a waterfall mode and do some logic on the final result. You should look into a library allowing parallel/waterfall execution. Like this

Waterfall: [Waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.waterfall)

```
    async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

Parallel: [Parallel](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.parallel)

```
async.parallel({
    collectionOne: function (callback) {
        collectionOne.find(query, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }
            callback(null, result);
        })
    },
    collectionTwo: function (callback) {
        collectionTwo.find(query, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }
            callback(null, result);
        })
    },
    collectionThree: function (callback) {
        collectionThree.find(query, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }
            callback(null, result);
        })
    },
    collectionFour: function (callback) {
        collectionFour.find(query, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return handleError(res, err);
            }
            callback(null, result);
        })
    },
}, function (err, results) {
    return res.status(200).json(results);
});
```

And in the final callback you can doo some logic or return response.

Comment: Thanks @twboc, the waterfall model looks promising. However, I still don't understand how to get a hold of all of the resulting statuses. Basically I'd like to call a function for _each_ result of the first function (i.e. for each metric found I want to retrieve the status and then process the set of statuses). This seems good for chaining in general, but the branching is what really gets me.

Comment: The Parallel method is of no use here because all three functions in his case are synchronous. Basically @langkilde you need to call the other function after completion of first function with results of first function therefore send the result as parameters or assign them to a variable that is accessible by both. (Keep Security in mind because this isn't a good practice - the global variable one). Promises is a concept which can be achieved using callback or explicitly using other modules like there are many. Best of luck.

Comment: In this case when you get an array of statues build your query with "$or" statement and all the things you are doing in a loop will be retrived in one query, and after that you can iterate over the resulting arrray and match it with correct data. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/ Put the queies from the or loop inside  { $or : [{query}, {query}....]} and then iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code, you are making network calls inside another network calls, which can lead to **callback hell** which can lead to misbehave of queries, in order to overcome that, you can use [promises](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html).

This will help you in avoiding callback hell as well as your query will also be resolved.

Sample code:-

```
new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
      return db.collection.find(function).exec()
      .then(function(result_of_first_query){
            return db.collection.findOne(function).exec()   //in this yopu can user the result of first query
      }).then(function(result_of_second_query){
             resolve(result_of_second_query);
      })
})
```

You can add more queries with each `.then`