# NodeJS How To Handle Concurrent Request To MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, async-await

I am having a problem with NodeJS.
When I am trying to post/update

- `One balance`
- `One account`
- posting from `Two different users`
- `at the same time.`

Example:

[image: example of t_account table]

I have API with ExpressJS for post data to the `t_account` table like this.

I need to get latest balance first from `max(id)` after each transaction.

I'm trying to get balance of 400 `NOT` 300

For Example:

1. Starting Balance = 100
2. 1st new post = 100, => balance =200
3. 2nd new post = 200, => balance =400

**Code Example:**

```
router.post('/saveBalance',async function (req, res) {
try {
    let SQL="SELECT balance FROM t_account WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM t_account WHERE no='"+req.body.no+"')";
    let queryResult=await db.myexec(SQL);
    let newBalance=queryResult[0].balance+req.body.balance;
    let SQL2="INSERT INTO t_account(no,balance) VALUES('"+req.body.no+"',"+newBalance+")";
    let queryResult2=await db.myexec(SQL2);
    res.status(200).json(  {
        error:"false",
        code:"00",
        message:"Balance Bank is saved",
        })
} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json(  {
        error:"true",
        code:"03",
        message:"Balance Bank failed to saved",
        })
 }})
```

The problem is when two user post data in the same time, I get the incorrect balance.

Code Example of Initializing my Transactions:

> ```
> const axios = require('axios');
> axios.post('http://localhost:3000/rbank/saveBalance/', 
>  {
>     "no":"11",
>     "balance":100
>   }
>  )
> axios.post('http://localhost:3000/rbank/saveBalance/', 
>  {
>     "no":"11",
>     "balance":200
>  }
> )
> ```

`MySQL` Console Logs

[image]
[image]

The last balance not right showing 300 instead of 400.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to lock the row that you are reading so that you can update this row before anyone else can read it. Look at [innodb-locking-reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html), specifically `for update`

From docs

> Locking of rows for update using SELECT FOR UPDATE only applies when
>   autocommit is disabled (either by beginning transaction with START
>   TRANSACTION or by setting autocommit to 0. If autocommit is enabled,
>   the rows matching the specification are not locked.

Comment: oh my god you are my savior....i think the problem is in the node.js (concurrent process)....actually in the mysql. i don't know about "FOR UPDATE" before.. thank you verymuch

Comment: Happy to help!! Just to add more context that this is not just node async issue. Think about a scenario where you app is running on multiple servers and you can enter into similar race conditions.

Comment: Yeah, MySQL has a ton of terrible "out-of-the-box" settings.  Defaults your Transaction level Giving READ HIGHER Priority than writes and Is why it was part of my answer.  Don't forget to check & TRY to use SET @@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE = "TRADITIONAL"; that acts more appropriate and will NOT leave you confused.  Default MySQL lets you insert NULLs into NOT NULL columns or provides you with a zero dates when you forgot to use datetime instead of timestamp or visa-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of your provided info, and not knowing more about NodeJS or your OS, Versions, setup etc. 
This is my thought process as what each issue I see.

## Check The Basics

1. As silly as this may actually be, there are so many unknown factors.

   - I see you are running this on your own computer,
   - If you run this 10+ times in a row, is the behaviour the same?

     - If the end result is different, Check processes running close.
   - If possible,

     - please do your basic computer check (reboot, close other programs)
     - if possible, check it on another computer too

   After that is out of the way check:

## Check saveBalance Function

1. Your `saveBalance',async function` Maybe the cause of the double `SELECT...SELECT` double `INSERT...INSERT`

   - My Gut tells me this is the issue based on the images, the order is wrong.

## Check Database Settings

1. If the `saveBalance',async function` is fine. I would check your `Database settings` as based on your MySQL Console Logs & that you are using `localhost`

   - Your image shows SELECT...SELECT...INSERT...INSERT...
   - But it should be SELECT...**INSERT...**SELECT...**INSERT...**
2. This Might be due to an issue with your MySQL Database Settings.

   - Please check your [Isolation Level.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html) To Check this run this in your MySQL

SQL Code:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.TX_ISOLATION;
```

It also, might interest you to use `START TRANSACTIONS;`
But be sure to enable [multistatements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30640814/1896134) in your config. and this is also directly tied to the `TX_ISOLATION` as well.

My example would modify your Query like so:

```
let SQL2="START TRANSACTION; INSERT INTO t_account(no,balance) VALUES('"+req.body.no+"',"+newBalance+"); COMMIT;";
```

## Try Other Accepted Code as your own

Lastly, I also recommend reading ['Approach to multiple MySQL queries with Node.js - One should avoid the pyramid of doom'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16243390/1896134)

I hope this helps.