# How to use database transactions in JavaScript with async functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the code below that gets some data from an external service and inserts it into some table in a database. It starts the transactions and commits it when all the data is inserted or rolls it back if an error occurres:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

class SomeClass
{
    async connect(params)
    {
        this.db = await mysql.createConnection(params);
    }

    async insertSomeRowsIntoSomeTable()
    {
        await this.db.execute('START TRANSACTION;');

        try {
            for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                //get the values to insert from an external service, for example.
                await const values = service.getValues();
                await this.db.execute('INSERT SomeTable .... <the values>...');
            }
            await this.db.execute('COMMIT;');
        } 
        catch (e) {
            await this.db.execute('ROLLBACK;');
        }
    }
}
```

but what if there is another async method `updateSomething` that updates a row in some table with a single update query and the client calls it while `insertSomeRowsIntoSomeTable` method is still running? Obviously, the updated data will be lost if the an error occurres in `insertSomeRowsIntoSomeTable`.

If there is another method that initiates its own transaction, for example, we unexpectedly get the nested transaction.

The only idea I have at the moment is to make all the operations with the database atomic by moving all the transaction logic to the stored procedures, for example, but it look like a workaround but not a solution.

Having a separate database connection in each async method is not an option, for the obvious reasons.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185816/nodejs-how-to-handle-concurrent-request-to-mysql

Comment: Don't use a single shared connection (what you called `db`) for all methods of your instance. Use on connection per transaction/method, and pool them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution is to use pool:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

class SomeClass
{
    async connect(params)
    {
        this.db = mysql.createPool(params);
    }

    async insertSomeRowsIntoSomeTable()
    {
        const connection = await this.db.getConnection();
        await connection.execute('START TRANSACTION;');

        try {
            for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                //get the values to insert from an external service, for example.
                const values = await service.getValues();
                await conn.execute('INSERT SomeTable .... <the values>...');
            }
            await connection.execute('COMMIT');
            await connection.release();
        } 
        catch (e) {
            await connection.execute('ROLLBACK');
            await connection.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Here you borrow connection from the pool in your `insertSomeRowsIntoSomeTable()` and if other async functions follow the same pattern this connection will be exclusively used by one transaction code path only until released