# How to keep previous successfully fetched data when using useQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm currently working on implementing a GET request using `useQuery` from the `react-query` library. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```js
import queryString from "query-string";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
  
const { query } = useRouter();

const { data: statsData, isLoading: statsLoading } = useQuery(
    ["stats", queryString.stringify(query)],
    ({ queryKey }) =>
      axios.get(`/statistics?${queryKey[1]}`).then(({ data }) => data),
    {
      onError: () => showErrMessage("500"),
    }
);
```

The issue I'm encountering is that whenever the request fails, it resets the previously fetched data. Here's how I'm attempting to display the data:

```js
{statsData?.total_sales}
```

How can I ensure that the data remains displayed even if the request encounters an error, rather than resetting to empty?

Comment: This sounds like a transaction commit/rollback issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633747/how-to-use-database-transactions-in-javascript-with-async-functions

Comment: This is what keepPreviousData is for, but agreed you’ll likely have confusing UI inconsistency unless to “rollback” the state of the thing tha caused the query to be fired agajn