# Pushing query results into an object

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm working on a private project to create a list of concerts I attended.

I have these tables:

- vi_concert (id, title, date, location)
- vi_artist (id, name, perma)
- vi_location (id, name, perma)
- vi_artist_concert (artist_id, concert_id)

I did 2 queries. One for the concert information, the second one for line up information:

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    var output = [];

    // Get Concert Information
    let concert = `SELECT c.date, c.title, l.name AS location 
    FROM vi_concert c
    INNER JOIN vi_location l ON c.location=l.id
    WHERE c.id = '${req.params.id}'`;

    db.query( concert, (err, result) => {
        if ( err ) throw err;
        output.push(result);
    });

    let lineup = `SELECT a.name, a.perma 
    FROM vi_artist_concert ac 
    JOIN vi_artist a ON a.id = ac.artist_id 
    JOIN vi_concert c ON c.id = ac.concert_id 
    WHERE ac.concert_id = '${req.params.id}'`;

    db.query( lineup, (err, result) => {
        if ( err ) throw err;
        output.push(result);
    });

    res.send(JSON.stringify(output));
});
```

When I call the URL localhost:3000/concerts/1 I get back the following:

```
[ ]
```

But I want something like this:

```
[
    "concert": {
        "date": "2019-02-16 19:30:00",
        "title": "Fancy title",
        "location": "Fancy location"
    },
    "lineup": [
        {
            "name": "Band 1",
            "perma": "band-1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Band 234",
            "perma": "band-234"
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: While I don't recall the node.js mysql client, I'm betting that it's asynchronous, and you will need to nest your `res.send()` call inside the `db.query` callback.  It might be easier with a Promise wrapper.

Comment: duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622746/approach-to-multiple-mysql-queries-with-node-js

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is **asynchronous**. Which means that your code sends `JSON.stringify(output)` without ever waiting for the database queries to end.

You will have to either:

- Do first query, **then** do second query, **then** send output
  or
- Do first and second query in parallel, **then** send output

First way without any additional library:

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    var output = [];

    // Get Concert Information
    let concert = `SELECT c.date, c.title, l.name AS location 
    FROM vi_concert c
    INNER JOIN vi_location l ON c.location=l.id
    WHERE c.id = '${req.params.id}'`;

    let lineup = `SELECT a.name, a.perma 
    FROM vi_artist_concert ac 
    JOIN vi_artist a ON a.id = ac.artist_id 
    JOIN vi_concert c ON c.id = ac.concert_id 
    WHERE ac.concert_id = '${req.params.id}'`;

    db.query( concert, (err, result) => {
        if ( err ) throw err;
        output.push(result);
        db.query( lineup, (err2, result2) => {
            if ( err2 ) throw err2;
            output.push(result2);

            res.send(JSON.stringify(output));
        });        
    }); 
});
```

Second way with the `async` library:

```
var async = require('async');

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    var output = [];

    // Get Concert Information
    let concert = `SELECT c.date, c.title, l.name AS location 
    FROM vi_concert c
    INNER JOIN vi_location l ON c.location=l.id
    WHERE c.id = '${req.params.id}'`;

    let lineup = `SELECT a.name, a.perma 
    FROM vi_artist_concert ac 
    JOIN vi_artist a ON a.id = ac.artist_id 
    JOIN vi_concert c ON c.id = ac.concert_id 
    WHERE ac.concert_id = '${req.params.id}'`;

    async.parallel([
        function(callback){
            db.query( concert, (err, result) => {
                if ( err ) return callback(err);
                output.push(result);
            });
        }, function(callback){
            db.query( lineup, (err, result) => {
                if ( err ) return callback(err);
                output.push(result);
            });   
        }
    ], function(err){
        if(err)
            throw err;
        res.send(JSON.stringify(output));
    })
});
```

You could also use **promises** if your DB driver supports them, but I will let you Google those on your own time.

Comment: This helped me, thanks! But how can I achieve, that I have to objects "concert" for concert and "lineup" for lineup like in my example?

Answer (score 0):

You're not waiting the records from the database before sending the response.
The `db.query()` method is an asynchronous operation and won't be available until the callback is called.

What you can change in your code to make it work is nesting query inside the callback of another, and send the response only after getting the db result.

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    var output = [];

    // Get Concert Information
    let concert = `SELECT c.date, c.title, l.name AS location 
    FROM vi_concert c
    INNER JOIN vi_location l ON c.location=l.id
    WHERE c.id = '${req.params.id}'`;

    db.query( concert, (err, result) => {
        if ( err ) throw err;
        output.push(result);

        // Nesting the second query in the first query callback

        let lineup = `SELECT a.name, a.perma 
        FROM vi_artist_concert ac 
        JOIN vi_artist a ON a.id = ac.artist_id 
        JOIN vi_concert c ON c.id = ac.concert_id 
        WHERE ac.concert_id = '${req.params.id}'`;

        db.query( lineup, (err, result) => {
            if ( err ) throw err;
            output.push(result);

            // Sending the response to browser only after getting the second result
            res.send(JSON.stringify(output));
        });
    });
});
```

An alternative to this is use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s.
Newer versions of Node.js support the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) syntax.